# lineTo() method doesn't accept array elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to draw lines according to coordinates in **points**' array, but it shows me the below error in the line when I call this method. When I write e.g. console.log(points[1][1]) it shows me the element. Could someone point at what I miss here?

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Here is my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var points = [[50, 50], [50, 100], [25, 120],
             [100, 50], [70, 90], [100, 90], [70, 120]];

function drawPoints(array) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(array[0][0], array[0][1]);
    for (var i = 1; i <= array.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(array[i][0], array[i][1]);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}

drawPoints(points);
```

Comment: Indexes start at `0` and end at `.length - 1`. Your loop goes from `1` to `.length` and therefor out of bounds. -> `i < array.length`

Comment: Thank you! It actually solved the problem.

Comment: You can answer your own questions (or in case of a simple typo like this one, consider deleting it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>


    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var points = [[50, 50], [50, 100], [25, 120],
            [100, 50], [70, 90], [100, 90], [70, 120]];

        drawPoints(points);

        function drawPoints(array) {

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(array[0][0], array[0][1]);
            for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                console.log("Value", array[i][0]);
                ctx.lineTo(array[i][0], array[i][1]);
            }
            ctx.stroke();
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: The problem was solved above. I should've writtern `.length - 1` instead of just `.length`. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Please check this below code,  I have updated this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var points = [[50, 50], [50, 100], [25, 120],
             [100, 50], [70, 90], [100, 90], [70, 120]];

function drawPoints(array) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(array[0][0], array[0][1]);
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {   // issue was here.
        ctx.lineTo(array[i][0], array[i][1]);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}

drawPoints(points);
```

Comment: Yeah. It was out of bounds. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, array indices are zero-based. That is, the first element's index is `0`, while the index of the last is `array.length - 1`.

The problem is that your for loop iterates until `array.length`, and will throw an error on the last iteration.

To solve it, change your loop into:

```
for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i++) { /*...*/ }
```

Or, even better, you can do something similar with ES6 things:

```
for (const elem of array.slice(1)) {
    ctx.lineTo(...elem);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Will check this .slice method out

Comment: @EagleCanFly Actually, the `.slice` method is not ES6... Just `for..of` and `...`. Slice is needed only because `for..of` iterates over the entire array...